# ruby error undefined method with class initializers

Tags: ruby, class

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix it? Can you direct me to a link that can? The full error is here:

```
(eval):9: undefined method `value=' for #<Slot:0x14ab40 @value=243, @name="TOM"> (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the code:

```
class Slot
  def initialize(name, value)
    @name = name
    @value = value
  end
end
a = Slot.new("TOM",243)
if a.value = 243
  puts "hello TOM"
end
```

Comment: There's no method for setting value. Did you mean to have an attr_accessor?

Comment: Add `attr_accesstor :name, :value` inside your class if you want other classes to be able to read and write those values from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby and most popular programming languages, `=` is used to assign a value to a variable, and `==` is used to compare two variables.

Therefore, your code should be:

```
if a.value == 243
    ...
```

Also, you need to define an attribute accessor for `value`:

`attr_accessor :value`

or

`attr_reader :value`,

depending on whether or not you want `value` to be writeable outside the class.

Comment: Correct, but note that it still won't work, as `Slot` lacks an accessor method for `@value`.

Comment: so how would i fix this?

Comment: Welcome to an excellent `ruby` feature, you can add methods to your program through so called [*metaprogramming*](http://goo.gl/QI0nlm). As a matter of fact the statement `attr_reader :value` will define a *method* `value` which is exactly what you are trying to call in `if a.value == 243`. If you want to set the `@value` attribute through a `value=` method (another special feature in `ruby`, most languages do not allow `=` in method names) you should define it through `attar_writer :value`, if you want to define *both* of them there is `attr_accessor :value` to the rescue, it will do that.

Comment: @user3250068 If this answers your question, could you please accept it? It somehow got unaccepted when I edited it. Thanks!